# How to get which row tapped of UITableView when cell has UIView on it

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

i have 3 labels over UIView in a Cell of UITableView. How i get which row is tapped by user. Pls Provide sample code.

Comment: You can use the UITableViewDelegate method "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath", the indexPath.row is what you're looking for.

Comment: i have put UIView over a cell and put labels over it. and tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working

Comment: show your code ?

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL How Can i show?

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL Now i delete UIView and now it is still not working.

Comment: @Aakash Just adding a uiview will change nothing on behaviour. didSelectRow should be called. Are you assigning  the delegate to the viewcontroller?

Comment: @FabioBerger yes delegates added to viewcontroller. but i can't understand why On tapping on row or on any Label DidSelectOnRowAtIndexPath not working..

Comment: @Aakash OK, please add the code from the viewcontroller which controls the tableview.

Comment: @FabioBerger. i am doing in parts as code is bit long

Comment: @Aakash you can remove the code that is related to the issue.

Comment: @FabioBerger i think i figured out the problem. i have set gesture recogniser on 2 labels to get which label tapped. when i remove gesture recogniser didSelectRow works perfectly. Now problem is if i remove gesture recogniser then how will i know which label tapped?

Comment: @Aakash You could track the touch in the UI view. Create a subclass of UIView and overwrite the touchesBegan method. (Dont forget to call super)
With the set of touches provided in touchesBegan, you can get the location where the finger hit the view and check if it is inside each labels frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a protocol in your custom cell class to define wich row has been selected. For example, you can do this:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
   func didCellSelected(cell: CustomCell)
}

class Cell: CustomCell{
  var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
  /..../
  func selectCell(){
    if(self.delegate != nil){
      delegate.didCellSelected(cell: self)
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can simply implement `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and identify the row from the indexPath. Maybe if you want to only identify the row you might be use this method. Otherwise you can define a custom delegate for example if you want to select label for a specific row.

Comment: 'tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)' is not working because all labels are over UIView so when i tapped over a row in UITableView Cell I actually tapped UIView not Row of UITableView

Comment: So you need to implement a protocol into your custom cell class and make a UITapGesture in your UIView. This protocol must have the function "didCellSelected" as I explained before.

Comment: First you can put this gestures on `AwakeFromNib()`. Second, you need to put delegate to self in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and Third, you need to implement `CustomCellDelegate` on your ViewController